# What is the format of calling a method from another class?

Tags: java, arrays, class

If I would like to call a method from another class to input it into the current class that I am working on, how do I format it to call the method? How is the code written to call for the method. Currently I have my floats array that is a method? written in another class and I would like to call for the function to be inputed into the class that I am working on. I honestly don't mean to sound ignorant but I am having hard tie trying to grasp how java works. Thanks.

This is what i put. The float array and the name = the name of the class? I am pretty sure it is incorrect because I am getting an error that myPickNumbers cannot be resolved.

```
float[] myFloats = myPickNumbers.pickNumbers();
```

I am trying to take this:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pickNumbers {
    Scanner readInput = new Scanner(System.in);


        float [] pickNumbers(int choice){
            float []myFloats = new float[2];
            do { //do loop will continue until user enters correct response
                System.out.print("Please enter 2 numbers separated by a space in the formats of floats: "); //will prompt user to enter 2 floats
                try {
                    myFloats[0] = readInput.nextFloat(); //will read first float entered
                    myFloats[1] = readInput.nextFloat(); //will read second float entered   
                    if (choice == 4 && myFloats[1] == 0.0f) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot complete calculation. Cannot divide by 0, please try again.");
                        myFloats[0] = myFloats[1] = 0.0f;
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;

                } catch (final InputMismatchException e) {
                            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid input. Try again.");
                    readInput.nextLine(); // discard input that is not a float
                    continue; // loop will continue until the correct answer is found
                }
            } while (true);
            return myFloats;
        }
}
```

And put it into this:

```
public class Calculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputOperation;
    String operatingWord[] = { "adding", "subtracting",
                              "multiplying", "dividing" };
    //array of operations to display to user
    Selection mySelection = new Selection();    
    String menu = "Welcome to John Doe's Calculator" //next line print out line for welcome
        + "\n 1. Addition"//next line option 1 for addition
        + "\n 2. Subtraction" //next line option 2 for subtraction
        + "\n 3. Multiplication" //next line option 3 for multiplication
        + "\n 4. Division" //next line option 4 for division
        + "\n 5. Exit\n"
        + "====================================\n\n"; //next line option 5 for exit then leave a blank line
    Symbol.newSymbol(menu);
    Symbol.displaySymbol();


    while (!(inputOperation = mySelection.selectionOne()).equals("5"))
        Symbol.newSymbol("\n");
        Symbol.displaySymbol();

        float[] myFloats = myPickNumbers.pickNumbers();
```

Comment: If "myPickNumbers cannot be resolved",  the error is that you haven't imported or aren't using the proper name for the `myPickNumbers` class.  But the syntax you are using looks correct.

Comment: You can't call an array, but you can call a method.  And if `pickNumbers` is a method declared something like `public float[] pickNumbers() { ...the code... }`, then your syntax will work.  If this isn't a method, please show us some code so that we can figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: One idea is to create a public getter method for your outside class, which will return the needed array once it is called. This way, you won't have to worry about unauthorized access to that array

Comment: `"I would like to call an array"` -- arrays can't be "called". Methods can, and that's what you should do.

Comment: "Here array!! Here buddy!!"

Comment: Regarding your error -- please show more code, describe more context, show the whole error message. Let's get full information so we can better be able to help.

Comment: I added the code, the last time is where I am running into this cannot be resolved error.

Comment: Thank you for posting your code.  A comment: it's a very bad idea to have a method in your class that is the same name as your class.  Class names by convention should start with upper-case letters, method names should start with lower-case letters.  A _constructor_ for a class looks almost like a method that has the same name as the class; if you have a method that also has the same name, it's legal but **very** confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a variable, myPickNumbers that you neither declare nor initialize. You must first declare it and initialize it before you can use it:

```
pickNumbers myPickNumbers = new pickNumbers();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first declare a new pickNumbers object

```
pickNumbers myPickNumbers = new pickNumbers();
```

Then you can call the pickNumbers() method but you have to include a parameter of type int e.g

```
float[] myFloats = myPickNumbers.pickNumbers(5)
```